# Fix sql injection on Rails model scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

There is a model scope I have been trying to refactor, Brakeman is complaining about it so I thought it was a good idea to fix it since we were scanned by bots who are looking for our site vulnerabilities.

```
scope :cash_deal_aggregated, -> (filter = '') {
  select("deals.*")
  .from([Arel.sql(
    "(SELECT DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(cash_deal_details.cash_deal_id, 0.1*deals.id)) deals.*
      FROM deals
      INNER JOIN portfolios ON portfolios.id = deals.portfolio_id
      LEFT JOIN cash_deal_details ON deals.cash_deal_detail_id = cash_deal_details.id
      #{filter}) deals"
    )]
  )
}
```

The scope above is used like this:

```
filter = "WHERE portfolios.client_id = #{client_id}"
deal_records = deal_records = Deal.cash_deal_aggregated(filter)
```

And it is also used like this:

```
deal_records = Deal.cash_deal_aggregated
```

Initially I tried to fix it by adding the `filter` directly in the query but then got multiple errors.

Appreciate your suggestions for this refactor.

Comment: Try to refactor the inner join and left join with the Rails association.

Comment: @SantoshAryal how that will help?

Comment: If the brakeman is sending you warning about the possible SQL injection, try to test the SQL injection injecting the SQL. Brakeman also may send SQL injection warning for the SQL commands which are not formatted well i.e `select * from books;` to `SELECT * FROM 'BOOKS';`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: IMO, if you can refactor string interpolation in your SQL (`#{filter}` and `#{client_id}` in your case) to Arel or ActiveRecord, brakeman should no longer complain.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap ActiveRecord's `connection.quote()`, wrap `client_id` in this method, e.g., in your case, try this

```
"WHERE portfolios.client_id = #{connection.quote(client_id)}"
```

I also got these errors from brakeman earlier and this resolved it.

Comment: Sounds good, also seems like I can use https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions

Comment: Yes, but `connection.quote` will fit better for your scenario because you are interpolating just one value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the refactor. Credits to [Rajdeep Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564298/rajdeep-singh)

```
scope :cash_deal_aggregated, -> (client_id = nil) {
  filter = "WHERE portfolios.client_id = #{connection.quote(client_id)}" if client_id
  select("deals.*")
  .from([Arel.sql(
      "(SELECT DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(cash_deal_details.cash_deal_id, 0.1*deals.id)) deals.*
      FROM deals
      INNER JOIN portfolios ON portfolios.id = deals.portfolio_id
      LEFT JOIN cash_deal_details ON deals.cash_deal_detail_id = cash_deal_details.id
        #{filter}) deals"
      )]
    )
  }
```